# Is it possible to have array index as char?

Tags: java, arrays, char

count[str1.charAt(i)]

charAt() returns char type. How can char type be used as index in array

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I saw this on geeksforgeeks, I wanted to understand how is this possible

Comment: Char can be converted to int.

Comment: A `char` is an integral type. Yes, that is legal.

Comment: charAt() returns the ascii value ?

Comment: @SHAURYACHOPRA, charAt() doesn't returns ASCII value. just check String class documentation. you'll find charAt() with definition. Its return type is char, but not int.   char charAt(int index)    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Unrelated: the other lesson from the question on `out()` that you just deleted: use meaningful names. Even for "simple" examples. When you just spend one character for variable names, it is really easy to end up with such stupid typos. So: use names that do what they say, and that say what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES! It is possible.
It is a basic rule of java.
We can assign char value to int type of variable. Now that int type variable will not store a character but its ASCII value. See the example

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num='a';
        System.out.println(num);//97
    }
}
```

you can see i've assigned 'a' into int type of variable.

In same case, whenever we pass char as index value, always ASCII value will be passed. As we know, 97 is the ASCII value of a.

So if we access an array by passing 'a', internally 97th index of array will be called.

```
int num='a';
System.out.println(args[num]);//AIOOBE
```

Here we got Exception like

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 97
        at Test.main(Test.java:4)**

Program is compiled fine, but we got exception at runtime because args is empty array right now.

Comment: A `char` value is **not** an ASCII value, but rather "A char value [...] represents Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) code points, including the surrogate code points, or code units of the UTF-16 encoding. " -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you for your suggestion. I am not saying a char value is an ASCII value, but i mentioned that every char value can be represented by an ASCII value or every character has its own ASCII code. Yes but i am sorry, i shouldn't use the word **ASCII** since unlike C or C++ , Java supports **UNICODE** character set.